# No route matches [PATCH] "/persons"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### I'm new to the ruby. He saw such a mistake, he looked through a lot of articles, I do everything exactly as instructed, but nothing comes out. With Create everything is in order but on the update swears.

> my action:

```
...

def edit
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    @person.update_attributes(person_params)
 if @person.errors.empty?
    redirect_to @person
 else 
    render 'edit'
 end
end

private
  def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:number, :family, :name, :patronymic, :other)
  end
```

> my views:

```
<h1>Редактировать личность</h1>
<%= form_for @person, url: persons_path do |f| %>
    <p>Номер</p>
       <p><%= f.text_field :number %></p>
...
       <p><%= f.submit "изменить базу" %></p>
<% end %>
```

> and router:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
     resources :persons
end
```

Comment: Please submit this question at https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ or rewrite in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass `, url: persons_path`, since `persons` is resource, `form_for @person` will figure out that it has to go to `update` action.

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
```

should be fine.
If you still do need to pass the `url`, it should be `url: person_path(@person), html: {method: "patch"})`

Read more about this topic in Rails Edge guide -
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification

**Note**:  As @engineersmnky also pointed, your `config/routes.rb` should traditionally have `resources :people` instead. Resource is specified in pluralized form.

If you generate scaffold with Rails - `rails g scaffold People name:string`, you will see that you get:

1. model - `person.rb`
2. controller - `people_controller.rb`
3. route helper - `resources :people`

Comment: additionally `ActiveSupport::Inflector` is intelligent enough to know the plural of `person` is `people` rather than `persons`

Comment: I was wondering the same. It should have been `resources :people`